# How do I set a geography point to be the North Pole?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, spatial

I tried to execute this query on my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance:

```
UPDATE ITEMS
SET GEOG=geography::STPointFromText('POINT(0 90)', 4326);
```

SQL Server returned the following error:

```
System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees
```

I also tried `POINT(0 89.99)` and got the same error.

How do I set a point to be the North Pole?

Comment: `SELECT geography::STPointFromText('POINT(0 90)', 4326)` doesn't raise any errors for me.

Comment: I've voted to close this as too localized because the problem isn't in the question at all. It's external to the data provided and specific to your configuration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. the problem was raised by a trigger enabled on the table.
the problem is that the trigger contain exactly the same code to update the GEOG field when GEO_LAT and LON field are updated... really strange but for now the problem is solved also without 0.0 and 90.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, with (or without) decimal points

```
DECLARE @a geography
SET @a=geography::STPointFromText('POINT(0.0 90.0)', 4326)
```

if this works - then something wrong with the ITEMS table